# ComboBox onChange event

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm new in JavaScript. I have 3 selects on jsp page:

```html
<select id="railwayServiceList" name="railwayService_id" 
    onchange="changeCompaniesCombo()"></select>
<select id="companyList" name="company_id" 
    onchange="changeCompaniesCombo()"></select>
<select id="departmentList" name="department_id"></select>
```

and JavaScript functions for `onChange()` event:

```html
function changeCompaniesCombo() {

    var railwayServiceList = document.getElementById("railwayServiceList");
    var companyList = document.getElementById("companyList");
    var selected = railwayServiceList.value;
    while (companyList.options.length) {
        companyList.remove(0);
    }
    <c:forEach items="${companies}" var="company" varStatus="loopStatus">
        if ("${company.railwayService}" == selected) {
            var option = new Option("${company.name}", "${company}");
            companyList.options.add(option);
        }
    </c:forEach>
}

function changeDepartmentCombo() {
    var departmentList = document.getElementById("departmentList");
    var companyList = document.getElementById("companyList");
    var selected = companyList.value;

    while (departmentList.options.length) {
        departmentList.remove(0);
    }
    <c:forEach items="${selected.departments}" var="department" varStatus="loopStatus">
        var option = new Option("${department.name}", "${department.id}");
        companyList.options.add(option);
    </c:forEach>
}
```

It works fine, but maybe there is some way to create a common function for all selects? (I have 8 selects). Data model is produced by Spring MVC controller.

Comment: I believe you can pass a parameter into the function you specify for the onchange event. If you pass the context ("this"), you may be able to get information about which one was selected, and handle it in a single changeXXXCombo() function. I haven't done anything with js for a while so I may be confusing it with another language, but I think you can do that

Comment: I also need to produce combobox with values. And I don't understand how to pass list of values. For example, Companies combo get values from ${railwayService.companies}, Department - from ${company.departments}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chained Selects Plugin for jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/chained/) solved my problem